# how to run sakai custom tool from maven

Tags: maven, sakai

mvn install sakai:deploy is running successfully but at run time it gives error

> org.sakaiproject.portal.api.PortalHandlerException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find registered context
>   for tool with ID sakai.employee
>       at org.sakaiproject.portal.charon.SkinnableCharonPortal.doGet(SkinnableCharonPortal.java:862)
>   caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to find
>   registered context for tool with ID sakai.employee
>       at ... (check the revision history for full stacktrace)

Answer (score 1):

Check catalina.out for errors when you start Tomcat.

The tool web app has not started up.

You'll need to resolve those errors before the tool will load.